# Batch test class passing but not covering execute method

Tags: unit-test, batch, class, method

```Apex
public with sharing class ContractBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful{
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(RecordsToBeUpdated_Accessor.getRecordsRelatingToCurrentOrFutureFYsTargets());
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contract__c> contracts){
        List<Contract__c>contractsToBeUpdated =new List<Contract__c>();
        DatedConversionRate rate1=ConvertionRateRetriever.getConversionRate('GBP');
        DatedConversionRate Rate2=ConvertionRateRetriever.getConversionRate('USD');
        String rateGBP =String.valueOf(rate1);
        String rateUSD =String.valueOf(rate2);
        String GBP=rateGBP.subString(49,57);
        String USD=rateUSD.subString(49,57);
        for(Contract__c contract : contracts){
            if(contract.Currency_Conversion_Rate_GBP__c!=GBP||contract.Currency_Conversion_Rate_USD__c!=USD){
                contract.Currency_Conversion_Rate_GBP__c=GBP;
                contract.Currency_Conversion_Rate_USD__c=USD;
                contractsToBeUpdated.add(contract);
            }
            update contractsToBeUpdated;
        }
        
      }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS

```apex
@isTest
public class ContractBatch_Test {
    @testSetup
    static void createTestRecord(){
        Contract__c contract = new Contract__c();
        contract.Account__c='0018E00001hMxXjQAK';
        contract.Status__c='In Negotiation';
        contract.Contract_Start_Date__c=system.Today()+30;
        contract.CreatedDate=system.Today();
        contract.Contract_End_Date__c=system.Today()+90;
        contract.Contract_Type__c='Contractual';
        contract.CurrencyIsoCode='EUR';
        insert contract;
    }

    @isTest
    static void testBatchExecuteMethod()
    {
        Contract__c qContract=[SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Currency_Conversion_Rate_GBP__c, Currency_Conversion_Rate_USD__c 
                            FROM Contract__c WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR OR CreatedDate > THIS_YEAR];
    
        qContract.Currency_Conversion_Rate_GBP__c='3.4';
        Test.StartTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new ContractBatch());
        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: That test should absolutely not pass unless `Account__c` is a text field, since your test code cannot see real data and you have hard-coded an Id. You've also got DML in a loop.

Comment: You only gain coverage for code that's executed as part of a test method. You also are responsible for constructing, in your test class, _all of the data_ your code needs to run. Best guess is that whatever `RecordsToBeUpdated_Accessor.getRecordsRelatingToCurrentOrFutureFYsTargets()` is doing, it's not returning any query (or the query returns no rows). Can't tell you what to do there without seeing that accessor class of yours too. Also, the `qContract.Currency_Conversion_Rate_GBP__c='3.4';` in your test method does nothing for you (you'd need to perform a DML update for a query to see that).

Comment: You also don't have any assertions. Code coverage is a side effect of unit testing. The real value in unit tests comes from showing that your code behaves properly, and to do that you need assertions. You make assertions on the output of running the code you're testing. Here, that would mean you query your contracts again (after `Test.stopTest()`) and ensure that their two conversion rate fields were updated to the values you expect (i.e. whatever is in the `gbp` and `usd` strings in your batch class).